# systemd service for ssh-agent with loading of identity files for each login

Tags: ssh, systemd, fedora, ssh-agent, github

I am trying to set-up an automated way to load my ssh keys at login.

I have the below configured:

```
❯ cat .ssh/config
Host github
    HostName ssh.github.com
    User git
    Port 443
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
```

When I attempt to login via `ssh -T git@ssh.github.com`, I am getting `git@ssh.github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`

To fix this, I execute the below:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" &> /dev/null; find ~/.ssh/ -type f -exec grep -l "PRIVATE" {} \; | xargs ssh-add &> /dev/null
```

After, I run again `ssh -T git@ssh.github.com` and now it works: `Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

If I place this in my `.zshrc` file, I get a new PID for `ssh-agent` at every login. To avoid this, I want to transform the command above into a systemd service.

I have performed [the steps outlined here](https://www.tomica.net/blog/2016/10/ssh-agent-service-in-fedora/) since I am running this in Fedora 39 under WSL. I also added the below variables to my `.zshrc`:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket"
```

The `ssh-agent.service` file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH key agent

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
Environment=DISPLAY=:0 # DISPLAY required for ssh-askpass to work
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 3
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c 'find ~/.ssh/ -type f -exec grep -l "PRIVATE" {} \; | xargs ssh-add &> /dev/null'
ExecStop=kill -15 $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Doing a `systemctl --user daemon-reload`, followed by a `systemctl --user enable ssh-agent && systemctl --user start ssh-agent` starts the service successfully, however, when attempting to do `ssh -T git@ssh.github.com` I am getting the same error message until I run `find ~/.ssh/ -type f -exec grep -l "PRIVATE" {} \; | xargs ssh-add &> /dev/null` which then works. The issue persists across reboot and/or new shell logins.

Just having `AddKeysToAgent` configured won't automatically add the keys and this is why I need to add them manually through a command instead.

Is there something I am missing here with this setup? Please help.

Comment: Try removing the `&> /dev/null` and see if your commands are complaining about anything

Comment: Yes, it says some error connecting to agent even though the agent has PID and service is running.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the entire machine seems to have fixed it. This is also working when using another shell like FISH, but this needs to be declared in the shell config:

```
❯ bat --style=plain ~/.config/fish/conf.d/_ssh_agent_init.fish
if status is-login
  set -gx XDG_RUNTIME_DIR "/run/user/$(id -u)"
  set -gx SSH_AUTH_SOCK "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket"
end
```

Basically, whichever shell is used, needs to have these env vars declared for this to work and a new shell need to be initialized (sourcing doesn't always work):

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket"
```

After setting these in your shell's RC file, you need to restart your shell:
`exec bash` or `exec zsh` or `exec fish`, depending on the shell.